# How to prove this identity: $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \: \underbrace{\int_a^x\cdots \int_a^x}_r f(u) \, (du)^r = e^x \int_a^x f(u) e^{-u} \, du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to show this identity?

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \: \underbrace{\int_a^x\cdots \int_a^x}_r f(u) \, (du)^r = e^x \int_a^x f(u) e^{-u} \, du$$

Comment: If $f$ a multivariable function?

Comment: @Yonatan I have not seen question but i think f is a multivariable function

Comment: The use of $x$ for both bound an unbound variables may be confusing

Comment: Let me doubt that. What would be the meaning of $e^x$ ?

Comment: You need to find the exact question

Comment: @Yonatan: I don't see a problem in this question, with a function of a single variable.

Comment: But you integrate it $r$ times, after the first time you get a constant. and like Hagen von Eitzen said $x$ is used too much.

Comment: @Yonatan: "after the first time you get a constant": no, you get a function of $x$ (an antiderivative of $f$).

Comment: So what about $dx^r$ you don't integrate the same function. $x$ is use to the varible and the bound.

Comment: We can write the identity as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = e^{x}\int_a^xf(t)e^{-t}{\rm d}t$
where $f_{n+1}(x) = \int_a^xf_n(t){\rm d}t \implies \frac{df_{n+1}(x)}{dx} = f_n(x)$ with $f_0(x) = f(x)$. It can be proven by differentiating both sides (assuming the sum converges).

Comment: The formula is incorrect, if you take $f=1$, the left hand side is $\sum_r (x-a)^r$ and the right hand side is $e^{x-a}-1$.

Comment: @copper.hat For $r=2$ we have (using more clear notation) $\int_a^x\int_a^{t_1} f(x){\rm d}t_2{\rm d}t_1 = \frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}$ when $f(x)=1$ and similar for higher terms so the LHS is $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(x-a)^r}{r!} = e^{x-a}-1$. OP should edit the question using a more clear notation as it's a mess right now.

Comment: @Winther: Thanks! I added an answer using my own interpretation below.

Comment: @artictern: Your proposed edit would (perhaps unintentionally) have made only the inner integral a function of $u_r$ rather than $u$.  So it would have changed the OP's intent.

Comment: @hardmath According to Dr. MV's accepted answer, I was correct to interpret the integrand as only a function of one of the dummy variables, but the issue was I should have interpreted the $x$s in the upper bounds as $x,u_{r-1},\cdots,u_1$.

Comment: At any rate, I am downvoting OP's question. fsuluova, the amount of effort it would have taken you to ask a question with meaningful, standardized notation is far outweighed by the amount of effort you've required of me (and, safe to assume, other lurkers) to puzzle what kind of integral you were referring to. I suppose I could have worked with the right-hand side in order to figure out how to interpret the left-hand side, but it is a good rule of thumb to not make [figuring out how to interpret your question harder than the question itself](http://i.imgur.com/p1oZh0q.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the inner integral

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^{x_2} \int_a^{x_1}f(x_0)\,dx_0\,dx_1&=\int_a^{x_2}\int_{x_0}^{x_2}f(x_0)\,dx_1\,dx_0\\\\
&=\int_a^{x_2} f(x_0)(x_2-x_0)\,dx_0 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, upon integrating $(1)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^{x_3} \int_a^{x_2}\int_a^{x_1}f(x_0)\,dx_0\,dx_1\,dx_2&=\int_a^{x_3}\int_a^{x_2} f(x_0)(x_2-x_0)\,dx_0\,dx_2\\\\
&=\int_a^{x_3}\int_{x_0}^{x_3}f(x_0)(x_2-x_0)\,dx_2\,dx_0\\\\
&=\int_a^{x_3}f(x_0)\frac{(x_3-x_0)^2}{2!}\,dx_0
\end{align}$$

Continuing, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^{x_{n+1}} \int_a^{x_{n}} f(x_0)\frac{(x_{n}-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\,dx_0\,dx_{n}&=\int_a^{x_{n+1}}\int_{x_0}^{x_{n+1}}f(x_0)\frac{(x_{n}-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\,dx_{n}\,dx_0\\\\
&=\int_a^{x_{n+1}} f(x_0)\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_0)^{n}}{(n)!}\,dx_0
\end{align}$$

Finally, let $x_{n+1}=x$, sum over $n$ and use the series representation for the exponential function $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks!  And good to see you again.  I've edited to provide more details to perhaps reverse the down voters wrath.  ;-))  -Mark

Answer (score 3):

We can show that
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_a^t \cdots \int_a^{\tau_{k-2}} \int_a^{\tau_{k-1}} f(\tau_k)  d \tau_1 \cdots d \tau_k = e^t \int_a^t f(\tau) e^{-\tau} d\tau$.

Start with the differential equation
$\dot{x}(t) = x(t) + f(t)$ subject to the initial condition $x(a) = 0$.
We need some conditions on $f$ to ensure integrability, etc., I will
assume that $f$ is measurable and bounded on bounded intervals. It is
clear that $x \mapsto x+f(t)$ is uniformly globally Lipschitz.

Pick some arbitrary $T>a$, we will examine solutions on $[a,T]$.

The  Picard–Lindelöf theorem shows that the equation has a unique solution and
it is easy to verify that $\hat{x}(t) = \int_a^t e^{t-\tau}f(\tau) d \tau$ is
the solution.

Furthermore, the Picard iteration shows that the solution is a fixed
point of the operator $(P x)(t) = \int_0^t (x(\tau) + f(\tau)) d \tau$,
and furthermore, starting with $x_0(t) = 0$, the sequence $x_n$ given
by $x_{n+1} = Px_n$ converges uniformly (in $C[a,T]$) to the solution.

In particular, for any $t \in [a,T]$ we have
$\lim_n x_n(t) = \hat{x}(t)$.

Note that $x_1(t) = \int_a^t f(\tau) d \tau$ and if
$x_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_a^t \cdots \int_a^{\tau_{k-2}} \int_a^{\tau_{k-1}} f(\tau_k)  d \tau_1 \cdots d \tau_k$,
then
$x_{n+1}(t) = \int_0^t (x_n(\tau_{n+1}) + f(\tau_{n+1})) d \tau_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \int_a^t \cdots \int_a^{\tau_{k-2}} \int_a^{\tau_{k-1}} f(\tau_k)  d \tau_1 \cdots d \tau_k$,
from which we obtain the above result.

Comment: @Winther: I removed my comment. I do think the notation is incorrect, not just bad.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $$F_0(x):=f(x),F_r(x):=\int_a^x F_{r-1}(x)\,dx$$ and $$F(x):=\sum_{r=1}^\infty F_r(x).$$

On one hand,
$$F(x)=e^x \int_a^x f(x) e^{-x}$$ is a solution of the differential equation

$$F'(x)-F(x)=f(x).$$

On the other hand,

$$\left(F_r(x)\right)'=F_{r-1}(x)$$

so that $$F'(x)-F(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty F_r(x)-\sum_{r=1}^\infty F_r(x)=f(x).$$

Comment: can you please mention $S(x)$ and $F(x)$ rule.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. This is a succinct (if notationally abusive) approach.

Comment: @copper.hat: thanks for the support. Silent downvotes are of little use.

Comment: What does $\int_a^x f(x)dx$ mean?

Comment: @arctictern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol

Comment: @YvesDaoust At no point on that Wikipedia page does it explain that $\int_a^x f(x)dx$ is something you expect your reader to interpret as $\int_a^x f(u)du$. (Which, yes, I know is what you intend, but I don't understand your decision to abuse notation - what advantage or tradeoff is there to offset the cost of throwing readers for a loop?) As such, I can assume you either didn't read the Wikipedia page and assumed an explanation was there, linked to the wrong entry, or else you're deliberately being facetious and mocking me. Anyway, I'm not one of the ones that downvoted here.

Comment: @arctictern: I think you are taking me wrong. This notation was used in the OP, I just reproduced it. The OP silently changed that. Anyway, I don't see how one can misinterpret the notation.